# Remove Funnel Symbol from the Syncfusion GridDataControl

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I am using a Syncfusion GridDataControl in my application, the column header contains a small filter funnel like symbol in every column, this hinders the look of my application. I want to remove that symbol from my column headers.

I tried couple of options disabling but no luck.

The application is in WPF, C#.

Any suggestion/help will be appreciatable.

Thanks,
Manali.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion controls also supports the WPF properties.

I was trying to disable the filter funnel symbol, which appears because the property `showFilters` of the `GridDataControl` is set to `True`. The symbol was still appearing even after setting the property `showFilters` to `False`.

This was because it was getting overridden by `AllowFilter` property which by default is `true`.

In order to disable the filter completely, I also had to manually set `AllowFilter` property to `false`, hence the issue was resolved.